# Blank screen and css js not loading after magento2 installation

Tags: javascript, css, installation, magento2, screen

While going through the installtion of Magento2 in Ubuntu. many problems are occured.Magento2 code cloned through GitHub

1. Blank screen after running installtion command
2. css nd js not loading

I have tried setting up permission in apache2 in conf file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Errror -This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

**Solution**

1. Search protected function `isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)` under this function `$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);` and replace this with `$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));`
2. Copy index.php and .htaccess from pub to  .Edit require in index.php to `require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';`

> Error - CSS AND JS not loading

**Solution**

1. In file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf Navigate <Directory /var/www/>Change "AllowOverride None" to "AllowOverride All"
2. Add this at last in env.php located at <MagentoRootDirectory/app/etc>

```
    'system' => [
           'default' => [
               'web' => [
                   'unsecure' => [
                       'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                       'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
                   ],
                   'secure' => [
                       'base_media_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/media/',
                       'base_static_url' => '{{secure_base_url}}pub/static/'
                   ]
               ]
           ]
       ]
```

3. In etc/di.xml,Search `<item name="view_preprocessed" xsi:type="object">` Under that Modify this `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink` to `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`
4. Add this in db `INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;`
5. Add this in db `UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '0' WHERE core_config_data.path LIKE '%web/seo/use_rewrites%';`
6. Run this command: `sudo a2enmod rewrite`